# Remove everything up to and including triple newline

Tags: regex, powershell

I am very new to Powershell, so I am no doubt doing something really stupid that causes my attempts to get this to work to not actually work... but after an hour of struggling, I'd love a hand.

I have a file for which a triple newline (two empty lines) marks a boundary. I want only everything that comes after the boundary.

My latest fruitless attempt looks like this:

```
$content = Get-Content -Raw $Path
$content = $content -Replace '^.+`r`n`r`n`r`n', ''
```

All my attempts to even match a single new line have failed. The -Raw parameter is because I came to understand this would change the way newlines were processed, but it didn't change anything.

I am also aware the regex isn't ideal; I'd want to make it non-greedy but I want to get a super-basic test case working first given my unfamiliarity with whatever flavor of regular expressions Powershell supports. (I assume I can just stick a ? after the + to fix that, but first things first.)

The goal is to go from

```
useless metadata I don't care about
more useless metadata


actual content
```

to this:

```
actual content
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `(?:\r?\n){3}` to match triple line breaks

Comment: [`^(?:(?![\r\n]{3})[\s\S])*[\r\n]{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/TogNO7/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `` '`r`n' `` is a literal 4 char string, while `` "`r`n" `` is linebreak 2-char string. Your pattern would not match any line breaks. It is safer to use `\r` to match CR and `\n` to match LF in Powershell regex patterns.

Also note that there are several lines between the start of the string and your delimiter, but `.` does not match a newline by default, you need a `(?s)` inline modifier to make `.` match newlines, too.

Use

```
$content -replace '(?s)^.*?(?:\r?\n){3}'
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a Singleline option that makes `.` match newlines, too
- `^` - start of the string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\r?\n){3}` - triple CRLF/LF line break.

[image]

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%5E.*%3F%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%29%7B3%7D&i=useless%20metadata%20I%20don%27t%20care%20about%0D%0Amore%20useless%20metadata%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aactual%20content&r=).

Comment: I am an idiot. How could I have forgotten about options that tweak the behaviour of the . operator. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Stigma There is more than `(?s)`. ``'`r`n'`` is a literal 4 char string, while ``"`r`n"`` is linebreak 2-char string. Your pattern would not match any line breaks.

Comment: I probably would have figured that one out if I had stopped barking up all the wrong trees, but thank you for pointing out my other mistake(s). It is truly appreciated. :-)